# Phaser throws error as player being undefined during key event

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, game-development

config.js

```
var config = {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    physics: {
        default: "arcade",
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 200 },
        },
    },
    scene: [EvoGame],
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

evogame.js

```
class EvoGame extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super("EvoGame");
    }

    preload() {
        this.load.image("Squittle", "assets/squittle.png");
    }

    create() {
        let player = this.physics.add.image(400, 300, "Squittle");
        player.setBounce(0.2);
        player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

        this.input.keyboard.on(
            "keydown-D",
            function (player) {
                this.image.setVelocityX += 10;
            },
            this
        );
    }

    update() {}
}
```

When I try to move the image using the D key, I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setVelocityX' of undefined
    at EvoGame.<anonymous> (evogame.js:18)
    at KeyboardPlugin.emit (phaser.js:1906)
    at KeyboardPlugin.update (phaser.js:185828)
    at EventEmitter.emit (phaser.js:1905)
    at onKeyDown (phaser.js:92223)
```

I have the player defined in create() and if I do it without let, var, or const, it doesn't render the player image at all. I'm building the game using Phaser, and besides that it is just plain html, css, and javascript.

When I console.log the player in the create() function, it shows an object with x = 400 which is where i have it initially set. I tried to access it with this.player.x but it still shows it undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I'm not sure if it'll end up a permanent solution or cause an issue later. I'm going to post it here in case anyone would like to review or if anyone else is in a similar solution and would like to try it out.

Basically it had to do with this block.

```
create() {
        let player = this.physics.add.image(400, 300, "Squittle");
        player.setBounce(0.2);
        player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

        this.input.keyboard.on(
            "keydown-D",
            function (player) {
                this.image.setVelocityX += 10;
            },
            this
        );
```

Since I defined the image in the player variable, I should have been using the variable in the keyboard event function. It also did not require "this" to be used, and I would be able to access the x attribute with just player.x.

The new function is:

```
create() {
        let player = this.physics.add.image(400, 300, "Squittle");
        player.setBounce(0.2);
        player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
        console.log(this.player);

        this.input.keyboard.on("keydown-D", function (event) {
            player.x += 10;
        });
    }
```

PART TWO: Changing 'let player' to this.player allows the player variable to be used in the update function as well. 'let player' and 'player.x' ended up being temporary solutions as I thought, and this.player made it more accessible.